# AppState event persists across all app screens even when cleaned

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-hooks

I use the AppState API listener to run a function when the app comes from background to active state. I remove it on the useEffect cleanup, but it is still being called on the other screens like it was never cleaned.

```js
const MyRoute = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const appStateRef = useRef(AppState.currentState);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();

    function updateRouteData(nextAppState) {
      if (appStateRef.current.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
        getRoutes(); // <--
      }

      appStateRef.current = nextAppState;
    }

    AppState.addEventListener('change', updateRouteData);

    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener('change', updateRouteData);
    };
  }, []);

  // ...
}
```

The AppState event listener persists on the other screens.

react-native: "0.64.4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Instead of calling the appstate logic inside a useEffect, I call it with the useFocusEffect from the react navigation. When leaving the screen you can trigger a cleanup function to remove the listener.

I created a custom hook to use it on my app.

```js
const useAppStateListener = (callback) => {
  const appStateRef = useRef(AppState.currentState);

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      async function updateRouteData(nextAppState) {
        if (appStateRef.current.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
          await callback();
        }

        appStateRef.current = nextAppState;
      }

      AppState.addEventListener('change', updateRouteData);

      return () => {
        AppState.removeEventListener('change', updateRouteData);
      };
    }, [callback]),
  );

  return appStateRef;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the event listener in a variable and then remove it.

```
const appStateListener = AppState.addEventListener()

appStateListener?.remove();
```

Comment: I already did that, it is still being called on the other screens